# Jquery Hide all Div click function issue with appendTo content

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show-hide, appendto

I have a "Jquery Hide all Div click function" where a  button can hide/expand a specific DIV class. It's working if I put my hyperlink and workding inside the DIV, until I customized my DIV content with an appendTo function from a different content container.

Issue: When I click the span button, the displayed DIV (with hyperlink and wordings) will display. But when I click anywhere from the displayed DIV i.e. not hyperlink, the div will close. The hyperlink will work and will not close the DIV.

Help: Need help on how to disable when I click from any section or not hyperlink, AND not to close the displayed DIV.

Here's a mock-up of my issue - https://jsfiddle.net/g8e80hqb/

Here's my code -

```
<div class="Toggle_HideAll_Container">
    <div class="container">
<div class="menu_r1c1"></div><br>
<div class="menu_r2c1"></div><br>
</div>

<span>Button hide/expand 1</span>
</div>

<span class="content1">
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Content1 Link 1</a> Dont include this text in the jquery click<br><br>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Content1 Link 2</a> Dont include this text in the jquery click<br><br>
</span>

<span class="content2">
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Content2 Link 1</a> Dont include this text in the jquery click<br><br>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Content2 Link 2</a> Dont include this text in the jquery click<br><br>
</span>
```

Here's the jquery -

```
$( ".content1" ).appendTo( ".menu_r1c1" );
$( ".content2" ).appendTo( ".menu_r2c1" );

// Start Toggle Hideall DIV
$('.Toggle_HideAll_Container div').hide();

$('.Toggle_HideAll_Container span').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('div');
    $(".Toggle_HideAll_Container div").not($this).hide();
    $this.toggle();
   });
```

Appreciate any help on this or if you need more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `:contains()` within selector to specify `span` element which should toggle elements , as other `span` elements are contained within `.Toggle_HideAll_Container`

```
$('.Toggle_HideAll_Container span:contains(Button hide/expand 1)')
.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('div');
    $(".Toggle_HideAll_Container div").not($this).hide();
    $this.toggle();
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g8e80hqb/3/

Comment: Sorry to ask again - guest271314 ... how to replace the span:contains(Button hide/expand 1) with an id or class of the span?... if you don't mind. i.e.<span id="spanid>Button hide/expand 1</span>

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('.Toggle_HideAll_Container > span').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('div');
    $(".Toggle_HideAll_Container div").not($this).hide();
    $this.toggle();
});
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/g8e80hqb/5/).

**Explanation:**

> Previously, you were selecting all `span` under
>   `Toggle_HideAll_Container` but you only need the last `span` with text
>   `Button hide/expand 1` so, you can **either** give it an `ID` **or** select
>   direct `span child of`Toggle_HideAll_Container`.